# Can I force wget to use the secondary dns

Tags: networking, 16.04, server, dns, wget

I am trying to download something from NVIDIA website on a remote server using ssh. Iran is banned by the NVIDIA website.

My server's DNS servers are:

```
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.20.14
IP4.DNS[2]:                             8.8.8.8
```

I know if I could set the DNS to google's (8.8.4.4 or 8.8.8.8) then I'm able to surf the website and download from it. I already tried to change the DNS on the server but whatever I do it's the same as above.

Its the content of `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
uto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#auto enth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 172.16.143.8
        netmask 255.255.255.224
        gateway 172.16.143.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

This is the output of `ifconfig`

```
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 34:97:f6:dc:9f:ff  
          inet addr:172.16.143.8  Bcast:172.16.143.31  Mask:255.255.255.224
          inet6 addr: fe80::c8cd:597a:b384:a22b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2101 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1298 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:891719 (891.7 KB)  TX bytes:237702 (237.7 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:fb200000-fb220000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
```

I wonder why network id is `eno1`?!

I also installed `resolvconf` and followed instruction of this website

https://www.tecmint.com/set-permanent-dns-nameservers-in-ubuntu-debian/

the content of `/etc/resolv.conf` is preserved but the dns doesn't change

Yet, I might be able to use the secondary DNS to connect a website (using `wget` or other solutions)

Is it possible, what could I do?

Answer (score 1):

As a temporary solution, this might work for you.

On the server:

```
echo 8.8.8.8 | sudo tee /etc/resolve.conf
```

Then try downloading your file.

You should find what is in charge of setting your DNS servers and use its configurations to change your DNS servers.

From your output I guess you are using `Network-Manager`. Let's say your main connection is called `conn-name`.

First ignore auto dns (it should help you get rid of the first line):

```
nmcli connection modify Home ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes
```

Then set your desired DNS:

```
nmcli connection modify Home ipv4.dns 8.8.8.8
```

Reload connection (be aware that it might break your SSH session)

```
nmcli connection down conn-name && nmcli connection up conn-name
```

Comment: I will try your solution now, by the way I added more details to my question before your answer

Comment: Please note that the remote server is far, I hope I don't lose the connection to the server, I mean by accidently changing the ip addresss or downing the network (there is no problem wtith reboot)

Comment: Then reboot the server. That's the safest way to do it. Just change `/etc/resolv.conf` and download your file.

Comment: thanks, I was able to set the dns and its now `8.8.8.8`. When I did the same on my laptop I was able to connect NVIDIA website. However, on the server I still has the `403` error (forbidden). I forgot to say that on the server I must connect to an `ISP` that provides internet for users. Then maybe I have no control on their internet!? right?

Comment: Depends on where your ISP is located. It might answers your DNS requests by itself.

Comment: back to `wget`, here it speaks about `--bind-dns-address`, could it be a solution?, however my `wget` doesn't have such option (maybe not up to date)

Answer (score 0):

In case where ISP intercepts / modifies DNS requests best to move over to DNS over TLS. My netplan sets a static IP as well as one issued by router DHCP

```
#!/bin/bash
# static IP - DNS servers and don't use gateway for DNS
# https://netplan.io/examples
# https://netplan.io/reference
sudo cp ./01-netcfg.yaml /etc/netplan/.
sudo netplan apply
# DNS over TLS
# https://www.internetsociety.org/blog/2018/12/dns-privacy-in-linux-systemd/
sudo cp ./resolved.conf /etc/systemd/.
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
# test it...
resolvectl query bbc.co.uk # replace with nvidia
```

```
$ cat 01-netcfg.yaml 
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.202/24
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
        use-dns: false
      dhcp6: true
      dhcp6-overrides:
        use-dns: false
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
  renderer: networkd
  version: 2
```

```
$ cat resolved.conf 
[Resolve]
DNS=8.8.8.8
#FallbackDNS=
Domains=~.
#LLMNR=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#DNSSEC=no
DNSOverTLS=opportunistic
#Cache=yes
#DNSStubListener=yes
#ReadEtcHosts=yes
```